# Why can't I connect a color ramp to an attribute fill node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to set the color of instanced cubes, by setting an attribute, and using that attribute in my material shader

When I attach nothing to the value input, i can select a color and it properly changes the material color (so i know my shader is working)

When i try to connect my color ramp to that input, like below, i get a red line and my texture turns black.

[image]

The color ramp is coming out of a noise texture.

Why doesn't it like this color input (even though their both of type color)?

Also I know attribute fill is outdated, so if you have a workaround that uses a different blender3 node, that's fine too.

Comment: It's a field (note the dashed line) that's coming into a regular color socket. Also you're mixing legacy nodes with fields nodes which are not made to be compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometry nodes fields no longer has any nodes that can refer to attributes with names. Instead, names of attributes can be specified in the modifier. To output a field to an attribute, simply connect the field to the *Group Output* node. In the modifier, under 'Output Attributes', you can then specify the attribute to output it to.
[image: Image showing the node tree.]
[image: Image showing the modifier.]